# Develop an app,to retrieve contacts from phone B to phone A

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to Android. Please help me in doing this app.
I am using an Android Studio.
Take two phones A and B, where the app has to be installed.
I want to develop an app which retrieves the contacts and call log from phone B to phone A.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I write this app?", that is much too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: show the path how can i proceed......

Comment: This is possible, but Stackoverflow won't tell you how to write a sender and receiver app. Break you app's down into tasks. 1) app a get contacts, 2) app a package contents for sending 3) app a send contacts 4) app b receive contents  ... then go away try each task and come back to stack overflow when you have an issue AND code examples of what you tried with these tasks